# Got this error "Diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory" after adding library using cocoapods

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, cocoapods

I keep getting this issue after installing new library using Cocoapods. I'm using Swift 2.2 and Xcode 7.3.1. CocoaPods version is 0.39.0. If you faced with this issue before, could you share how you solved it, please?

[image]

Comment: Do a `pod update` or as suggest `pod install`.

Comment: I already did it, still getting the same error. :(